webpack.config.ts unable to use ts-loader for TypeScript files
I am beginning a new project which will be a React TypeScript website package, and I would like to use webpack to bundle and serve my website artifacts.
I have installed webpack, webpack-cli, and webpack-dev-server for starters. Since I am using TypeScript, I have also installed ts-loader, which is what is done in the webpack guide. I am also writing the webpack config in TypeScript as well, i.e. creating a webpack.config.ts file.
At this point, it seems as though I should be able to build my project, but I have been stuck debugging the following error from webpack-cli:
> webpack --mode=production --config ./webpack.config.ts

[webpack-cli] Unable load '/path/to/website/src/website/webpack.config.ts'
[webpack-cli] Unable to use specified module loaders for ".ts".
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module 'ts-node/register' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module 'sucrase/register/ts' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module '@babel/register' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module 'esbuild-register/dist/node' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module '@swc/register' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Please install one of them
npm ERR! code 2

I have found several GitHub issues and Stackoverflow posts which essentially recommend installing ts-node, which I later did, but I still receive the following (similar) error message:
> webpack --mode=production --config ./webpack.config.ts

[webpack-cli] Unable load '/path/to/website/src/website/webpack.config.ts'
[webpack-cli] Unable to use specified module loaders for ".ts".
[webpack-cli] value.replace is not a function
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module 'sucrase/register/ts' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module '@babel/register' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module 'esbuild-register/dist/node' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Cannot find module '@swc/register' from '/path/to/website/src/website'
[webpack-cli] Please install one of them
npm ERR! code 2

What is going on here? Should I swap out ts-loader for an alternative like babel-loader? Should I give up on writing a webpack.config.ts file? Should I get with the times and just use Vite?
Ultimately I'm just trying to get up-and-running with as FEW dependencies as possible, and I want to understand what I'm installing and why (and what the analysis of alternatives would be in each case). I'm not trying to fallback to using create-react-app since that obfuscates essentially everything that I am trying to understand.

Folder Structure:
./website
  |-package.json
  |-tsconfig.json
  |-webpack.config.ts
  |-src
  | |-index.tsx
  | |-components
  | |  |-App.tsx
  | |-static
  | |  |-index.html

package.json
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && rm -rf node_modules",
    "build": "npm run webpack",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode=production --config ./webpack.config.ts",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "!**/tests/**"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": ["@tsconfig/node18"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

webpack.config.ts
import path from 'path';
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
};

export default config;


References:

Unanswered Reddit post with same question
webpack-cli | GitHub Issue #1993
webpack-cli | GitHub Issue #4129
webpack | GitHub Issue #6106
ts-node | GitHub Issue #2000
Is it possible to write webpack config in typescript?
"webpack-cli": Failed to load 'webpack.config.ts' config, TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"


Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#err_unknown_file_extension?
